# Bootstrap dropdown checkboxes that emulates radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this dropdown menu with checkboxes:

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Stores
     </button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsSears" value="Sears"  />Sears</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsKmart" value="Kmart"  />Kmart</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsTarget" value="Target"  />Target</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qemaWP

As you can see, I can select all three checkboxes if I wanted.

How can I emulate a radiobutton group in the sense that I can only select one option? If I *check* a second option, then the first option would automatically be unselected.

Comment: why are you asking for boostrap 4 and in codepen you use boostrap 3.2?

Comment: I did not see bootstrap 3.2 in the tags.

Comment: i'm confused. why do you need bootstrap for a radio button? just use the default html radio and style it yourself

Comment: Why not just use radio buttons to start?  Is this for practice? I think you will need some JavaScript to do this, what have you tried with that?

Comment: Note as the question was tagged bootstrap 4 I edited it for that, feel free to go get a bootstrap 3 if that is desired.  I do no think it changes the answers though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do u mean this?

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Stores
     </button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="radio" id="IsSears" value="Sears" name="myRadioButton"/>Sears</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="radio" id="IsKmart" value="Kmart" name="myRadioButton"/>Kmart</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="radio" id="IsTarget" value="Target" name="myRadioButton"/>Target</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the base element (delegateTarget) as the place to attach the event handler, this is pretty easy.

```js
$('.dropdown-menu').on('change', 'input[type=checkbox]',
  function(event) {
    $(event.delegateTarget)
      .find('input[type=checkbox]')
      .not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
```

```css
body {
  padding: 20px;
}

.dropdown-menu label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Stores</button>
  <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsSears" value="Sears"  />Sears</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsKmart" value="Kmart"  />Kmart</label>
    <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsTarget" value="Target"  />Target</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: NOTE: once a radio button is set, you as a user cannot uncheck it, that is NOT supported by this answer

Answer (score 0):

try using `type="radio"` instead of `type="checkbox"` on the inputs

this will, in a basic sense, tell the browser to treat these in a group.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I emulate a radiobutton group in the sense that I can only select one option?

If you cannot change the type (from checkbox to radio) you can simulate the radio button with js:

```
$('.dropdown-item :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form.dropdown-menu').find('.dropdown-item :checkbox')
                                          .not(this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

```js
$('.dropdown-item :checkbox').on('change', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('form.dropdown-menu').find('.dropdown-item :checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Stores
    </button>
    <form class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsSears" value="Sears"  />Sears</label>
        <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsKmart" value="Kmart"  />Kmart</label>
        <label class="dropdown-item"><input type="checkbox" id="IsTarget" value="Target"  />Target</label>
    </form>
</div>
```